# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'candidatedetails' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql

I am geting this error. How should I solve this?

This is my create query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[candidatedetails](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [pname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [cno] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [pno] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [address] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [year] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [class] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [branch] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [totalfees] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [paidfees] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [pendingfees] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [idno] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_candidatedetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
```

This is the code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string q = "INSERT INTO candidatedetails(id,cname,pname,cno,pno,address,year,class,branch,totalfees,paidfees,pendingfees,idno) VALUES ('','"+cname+"','"+pname+"','"+cno+"','"+pno+"','"+address+"','"+year+"','"+class1+"','"+branch+"','"+totalfees+"','"+paidfees+"','"+pendingfees+"','"+idno+"')";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Candidate is registered");
            }
```

I am getting this error on line "com.executenonquery()"

Comment: Remove the id field since it's auto generated.

Comment: If it's a NOT NULL column, and you set the identity_insert so you can set it manually, you still have to provide a NOT-NULL value.  Also, check how '' is regarded.  It may be failing on NULLValue into a Not Null column.  It may be failing on a conversion error from string to numeric.  If you want the Identity to set the value automatically, then remove the reference to the ID column altogether from the insert command.

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` column is declared as `IDENTITY` so it auto-generates a value on insertion. You don't have to include it on your insert column list nor supply a value for it.

```
string q = "INSERT INTO candidatedetails(cname,pname,cno,pno,address,year,class,branch,totalfees,paidfees,pendingfees,idno) VALUES ('"+cname+"','"+pname+"','"+cno+"','"+pno+"','"+address+"','"+year+"','"+class1+"','"+branch+"','"+totalfees+"','"+paidfees+"','"+pendingfees+"','"+idno+"')";
```

Also, beware of generating your SQL dynamically like this, it's **prone to errors** (if one of your values has an unescaped single quote for example) and to **SQL injection** if the values come from user input or another unsafe source.

You should either create a Stored Procedure that receives these parameters, or build the sql with `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 1):

just Remove id form sql query:
Try this:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                con.Open();
                if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    string q = "INSERT INTO candidatedetails(cname,pname,cno,pno,address,year,class,branch,totalfees,paidfees,pendingfees,idno) VALUES ('"+cname+"','"+pname+"','"+cno+"','"+pno+"','"+address+"','"+year+"','"+class1+"','"+branch+"','"+totalfees+"','"+paidfees+"','"+pendingfees+"','"+idno+"')";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Candidate is registered");
                }
```